# SSH-like php socket server

Tags: php, sockets

I have a CLI php script that collects user input, processes it, and returns information based on it. Currently it is only possible to use it if you SSH into the server that the PHP is on and run `php scriptname.php`, however, I know that PHP can create socket servers. Would it be possible, and if so how, to create a socket server that listens for a connection and once a user connects, provides a terminal-like environment for the script to run in until the user disconnects? It would be a different instance of the script for each connected user as well. No authentication would be required.

Edit: if this isn't possible with PHP, what are other options?

Edit:
Some of the code I use is below

For collecting user input:

```
  echo "Enter a command or question... \n";
  $line = $this->input();
  $line = trim($line);
```

This calls the input function, which will use readline to get the user input and return it, and then the script interprets the input and generates a response based on it, and then will ask for more input. This script doesn't end unless you tell it to, I would like to be able to connect to it via a PHP socket server or similar so that I can send it commands without using SSH.

Edit:
So, I tried the `xinetd` server, and I can connect to it, but readline and many other things including the formatting that worked when accessing through SSH no longer works with telnet. Are there other ways to do this or ways to configure it to be more flexible as far as formatting and readline?

Comment: You could have the system administrator configure `xinetd` to run your script on a socket.

Comment: This uses telnet, right? @Barmar

Comment: `xinetd` is a generic server, `telnet` is a client.

Comment: @Barmar But what other options besides telnet do I have to connect to the server? Telnet is limited at best.

Comment: You can connect with any software that can make network connections. For instance, `netcat`.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know why `readline` won't print the prompt when using this?

Comment: `readline` is intended for use on terminals, it probably doesn't do the interactive features when input is a file, pipe, or network socket. The prompt may be getting buffered.

Comment: @Barmar As a side note, it may be useful if you posted an answer detailing how to do this with xinetd as some people may not be able to figure it out, if not I can post the answer myself.

Comment: Maybe you can configure this as an `sshd` service, and set it to allocate a pseudo-tty. Then the script will behave like an interactive login.

Comment: It seems like a more appropriate question for superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: @Barmar How would I configure it as an sshd service with the pseudo tty? I have posted on superuser and nobody has answered or commented yet.

Comment: Looks like that's not possible when configuring a service. Maybe you should just run your script using normal SSH: `ssh -t servername php scriptname`.

Comment: @Barmar I accomplished this by making the php script executable and then running it as a user's shell.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. You don't need an Apache webserver, or [PHP's built in web server](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) or anything like that. I mean you could use those things, but easiest to just write a PHP script and have it listen on some port. Either adjust you script or write another one that pipes stdio between a socket and your script. Generally there are PHP wrappers for whatever system C libs or POSIX libs you would use if you were writing in C. In your case you probably want to use [Sockets](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php). There is many examples in the [PHP sockets docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php).

To give the jist, this is a simple PHP echo server - it just prints back anything you type. I can't remember where I got this from so sorry for lack of attibutation:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. Only applies to httpd module. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting as it comes in. Only applies to httpd module.*/
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));
    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);
socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: But would it work properly with the existing code, or would I need to modify it so that the input was still accepted?

Comment: If your script is just inputting and outputting ASCII, it will work fine.

Comment: wouldn't `ob_implicit_flush();` be unnecessary since I am not using httpd? Or any web server for that matter.

Comment: The intention of `ob_implicit_flush()` in this script is to flush out `echo "$buf\n";`. The effect of this statement is equivalent to `ini_Set("implicit_flush", true);` which should be true in CLI mode anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be old, but here's I share a possible to achieve what you want. Actually it is called remote shell, where client connects to the server and the client can control the server.

Below code is an example (proof-of-concept) and need more improvement in term of security, memory management, client handler etc to make it run effectively as in production.

server.php

```
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = "192.168.0.150";
$port = 10000;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
socket_listen($sock, 5);

while(true){
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
    $output = shell_exec($input) . "\n";

    socket_write($client, $output, strlen($output));
    socket_close($client);
}
```

client.php

```
while(true){
    $fp = fsockopen("192.168.0.150", 10000, $errno, $errstr, 3600);
    echo ">";
    $f = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
    $out = fgets($f);
    
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp);
    }
    
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This above code open a single port `10000` and accept connection from client. Even if the client close the connection, the port is still up and waiting (only support single client).

The server actually just receive a string and execute it in `shell_exec` (not a secured way) then return it back to the client. This means, the client now can control the "ssh-like" terminal of the server.

Answer (score -1):

I used @Barmar's comment to help me set up an xinetd server.

You'll want to add the script to your services file, 
**/etc/services**:

```
...
myservice port/tcp # my service
```

and then add an xinetd configuration file, **/etc/inetd.d/myservice**

```
# default: on
# description: service script

service myservice
{
        socket_type             = stream
        protocol                = tcp
        wait                    = no
        user                    = gleblanc
        server                  = /usr/bin/php
        server_args             = /home/service/scriptname.php
        log_on_success          += DURATION
        nice                    = 10
        disable                 = no
}
```